# Problem with importing mysql workbench data

Tags: mysql, database, utf-8, workbench

I have a table and data. When importing, automatically importing data into the user table throws a foreign key error. How do I load data into a table?
I understand that the problem is in the foreign key and the difference in id and name, but how to import the data?
need to write some kind of request?

This is the csv of the loaded data

```
Administrator,j.doe@amonic.com,123,John,Doe,Abu dhabi,1/13/1983,1
User,k.omar@amonic.com,4258,Karim,Omar,Abu dhabi,3/19/1980,1
User,h.saeed@amonic.com,2020,Hannan,Saeed,Cairo,12/20/1989,1
User,a.hobart@amonic.com,6996,Andrew,Hobart,Riyadh,1/30/1990,1
User,k.anderson@amonic.com,4570,Katrin,Anderson,Doha,11/10/1992,1
User,h.wyrick@amonic.com,1199,Hava,Wyrick,Abu dhabi,8/8/1988,1
User,marie.horn@amonic.com,55555,Marie,Horn,Bahrain,4/6/1981,1
User,m.osteen@amonic.com,9800,Milagros,Osteen,Abu dhabi,2/3/1991,0
```

and this is the mysql code

```
-- Dumping data for table `countries`
--

LOCK TABLES `countries` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `countries` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `countries` VALUES (1,'Afghanistan'),(2,'Albania'),(3,'Algeria'),(4,'Andorra'),(5,'Angola'),(6,'Antigua & Deps'),(7,'Argentina'),(8,'Armenia'),(9,'Australia'),(10,'Austria'),(11,'Azerbaijan'),(12,'Bahamas'),(13,'Bahrain'),(14,'Bangladesh'),(15,'Barbados'),(16,'Belarus'),(17,'Belgium'),(18,'Belize'),(19,'Benin'),(20,'Bhutan'),(21,'Bolivia'),(22,'Bosnia Herzegovina'),(23,'Botswana'),(24,'Brazil'),(25,'Brunei'),(26,'Bulgaria'),(27,'Burkina'),(28,'Burundi'),(29,'Cambodia'),(30,'Cameroon'),(31,'Canada'),(32,'Cape Verde'),(33,'Central African Rep'),(34,'Chad'),(35,'Chile'),(36,'China'),(37,'Colombia'),(38,'Comoros'),(39,'Congo'),(40,'Congo {Democratic Rep}'),(41,'Costa Rica'),(42,'Croatia'),(43,'Cuba'),(44,'Cyprus'),(45,'Czech Republic'),(46,'Denmark'),(47,'Djibouti'),(48,'Dominica'),(49,'Dominican Republic'),(50,'East Timor'),(51,'Ecuador'),(52,'Egypt'),(53,'El Salvador'),(54,'Equatorial Guinea'),(55,'Eritrea'),(56,'Estonia'),(57,'Ethiopia'),(58,'Fiji'),(59,'Finland'),(60,'France'),(61,'Gabon'),(62,'Gambia'),(63,'Georgia'),(64,'Germany'),(65,'Ghana'),(66,'Greece'),(67,'Grenada'),(68,'Guatemala'),(69,'Guinea'),(70,'Guinea-Bissau'),(71,'Guyana'),(72,'Haiti'),(73,'Honduras'),(74,'Hungary'),(75,'Iceland'),(76,'India'),(77,'Indonesia'),(78,'Iran'),(79,'Iraq'),(80,'Ireland {Republic}'),(81,'Israel'),(82,'Italy'),(83,'Ivory Coast'),(84,'Jamaica'),(85,'Japan'),(86,'Jordan'),(87,'Kazakhstan'),(88,'Kenya'),(89,'Kiribati'),(90,'Korea North'),(91,'Korea South'),(92,'Kosovo'),(93,'Kuwait'),(94,'Kyrgyzstan'),(95,'Laos'),(96,'Latvia'),(97,'Lebanon'),(98,'Lesotho'),(99,'Liberia'),(100,'Libya'),(101,'Liechtenstein'),(102,'Lithuania'),(103,'Luxembourg'),(104,'Macedonia'),(105,'Madagascar'),(106,'Malawi'),(107,'Malaysia'),(108,'Maldives'),(109,'Mali'),(110,'Malta'),(111,'Marshall Islands'),(112,'Mauritania'),(113,'Mauritius'),(114,'Mexico'),(115,'Micronesia'),(116,'Moldova'),(117,'Monaco'),(118,'Mongolia'),(119,'Montenegro'),(120,'Morocco'),(121,'Mozambique'),(122,'Myanmar, {Burma}'),(123,'Namibia'),(124,'Nauru'),(125,'Nepal'),(126,'Netherlands'),(127,'New Zealand'),(128,'Nicaragua'),(129,'Niger'),(130,'Nigeria'),(131,'Norway'),(132,'Oman'),(133,'Pakistan'),(134,'Palau'),(135,'Panama'),(136,'Papua New Guinea'),(137,'Paraguay'),(138,'Peru'),(139,'Philippines'),(140,'Poland'),(141,'Portugal'),(142,'Qatar'),(143,'Romania'),(144,'Russian Federation'),(145,'Rwanda'),(146,'St Kitts & Nevis'),(147,'St Lucia'),(148,'Saint Vincent & the Grenadines'),(149,'Samoa'),(150,'San Marino'),(151,'Sao Tome & Principe'),(152,'Saudi Arabia'),(153,'Senegal'),(154,'Serbia'),(155,'Seychelles'),(156,'Sierra Leone'),(157,'Singapore'),(158,'Slovakia'),(159,'Slovenia'),(160,'Solomon Islands'),(161,'Somalia'),(162,'South Africa'),(163,'South Sudan'),(164,'Spain'),(165,'Sri Lanka'),(166,'Sudan'),(167,'Suriname'),(168,'Swaziland'),(169,'Sweden'),(170,'Switzerland'),(171,'Syria'),(172,'Taiwan'),(173,'Tajikistan'),(174,'Tanzania'),(175,'Thailand'),(176,'Togo'),(177,'Tonga'),(178,'Trinidad & Tobago'),(179,'Tunisia'),(180,'Turkey'),(181,'Turkmenistan'),(182,'Tuvalu'),(183,'Uganda'),(184,'Ukraine'),(185,'United Arab Emirates'),(186,'United Kingdom'),(187,'United States'),(188,'Uruguay'),(189,'Uzbekistan'),(190,'Vanuatu'),(191,'Vatican City'),(192,'Venezuela'),(193,'Vietnam'),(194,'Yemen'),(195,'Zambia'),(196,'Zimbabwe');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `countries` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `offices`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `offices`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `offices` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CountryID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Contact` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_Office_Country` (`CountryID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Office_Country` FOREIGN KEY (`CountryID`) REFERENCES `countries` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `offices`
--

LOCK TABLES `offices` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `offices` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `offices` VALUES (1,185,'Abu dhabi','638-757-8582\r\n','MIchael Malki'),(3,52,'Cairo','252-224-8525','David Johns'),(4,13,'Bahrain','542-227-5825','Katie Ballmer'),(5,142,'Doha','758-278-9597','Ariel Levy'),(6,152,'Riyadh','285-285-1474','Andrew Hobart');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `offices` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `roles`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `roles`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `roles`
--

LOCK TABLES `roles` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `roles` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `roles` VALUES (1,'Administrator'),(2,'User');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `roles` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RoleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `OfficeID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_Users_Offices` (`OfficeID`),
  KEY `FK_Users_Roles` (`RoleID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Users_Offices` FOREIGN KEY (`OfficeID`) REFERENCES `offices` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Users_Roles` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleID`) REFERENCES `roles` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--
```

Comment: your data makes no sense the design from the users tabke should be identical with the csv file, or you have to restuctre it, for exaMPÖE Administrator should be 1 User 2 and so on

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE countries;`